# Как обратиться к элементам контента подгруженным через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Подскажите такой вопрос. Как обратиться к элементам контента подгруженным через ajax.

Для примера. По кнопки происходит запрос $.ajax() и в указанный див вставляется какой-то контент.

```
//к примеру
<span id="newhtmlajax">подгруженный контент</span
```

При дальнейшей попытки обратиться к уже подгруженному контенту ничего не происходит, не получается через $("#newhtmlajax") ...

Подскажите получается нельзя так обращаться или что то заведомо не правильно делаю?

Comment: Для примера вот страница

http://new.texno-proekt.ru/1.html

Comment: После подгрузки контента в ajax `$(".ajaxcontent").html(html);` добавьте строчку `$('#formback186').validate();` и все заработает!

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от конкретного кода. Что и как предполагается делать с `#newhtmlajax`.

Например, можно задать событие (blur, focus, load, resize, scroll, unload, beforeunload, click и т.д.).

```
$(function(){
  // jquery до версии 1.7
  $(document).delegate('#newhtmlajax', 'click', function(){ ... });

  // или
  $('#newhtmlajax').live('click', function(){ ... });

  // версия 1.7 и выше
  $(document).on('click', '#newhtmlajax', function(){ ... });
})
```

Подробнее по событиям здесь http://api.jquery.com/on/

После подгрузки будет работать `$("#newhtmlajax")`. Без примера кода сложно сказать.

Comment: Вот для примера создал 2 страницы.

Первая - http://new.texno-proekt.ru/1.html
На которой присутвует сразу в контенте код который обрабатывается js (click и validation) ...
и точно такой же код подгружается через ajax (с другой страницы), в коде всё видно, но её тот JS код при обращении почему то не видит?

что именно не правильно, тип обращения к объекту?

Comment: Почему не видит, по клику работает `$(document).on('click', '#formback186 input', function(){ ... })`

Comment: Вы лучше объясните, что хотите получить в результате? Какие действия должны быть в подгруженной форме? Так мы быстрее разберемся )

Comment: По клику на ссылку, подгружается форма. Которая у меня проверяется на заполнения плагином jquery.validate.js ...

Обычно я инициализирую плагин указав просто 
$('#form-id').validate();

Для подгруженного же контента не получается так.

В примере да я показал что клик через "$(document).on('click'" - работает, а через "$(".clk").click(function ()" нет ...

Comment: Вставьте в загружаемую страницу (2.html) под форму #formback186 код `<script>$('#formback186').validate();</script>`

Comment: Я знаю что этот вариант, работает.
Но задача или вопрос в том из общего кода на основной страницы который. От туда как сделать что бы заработало $('#formback186').validate(); 

Просто это я сделал это для примера, что бы понять вообще возможно такое или нет.

Comment: После подгрузки контента в ajax `$(".ajaxcontent").html(html);` добавьте `$('#formback186').validate();` и все заработает!

Comment: mr.Mouse, спасибо огроимное за ответ.. реально спасли.. уже 3 день ищу решение)